# Setting Object jQuery Set up?

Tags: jquery, object, settings, off-canvas-menu, offsite

I am currently trying to use a jQuery plugin that will allow my site to push the right and will reveal the side navigation (offsite navigation) However the developer is saying I must use settings object and my professor doesn't what I am talking about so I have to ask someone for help. [This is the plugin I want to use](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?sSiFsN3Q) and here are the [directions](https://github.com/ahmedrad/sliiide).

Lastly I have link the jQuery file to my site perfectly but I do not how to initialize the code to work.

Here is my code

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#closead").click(function() {
        $("#ads").css("display","none");
});

$frameheight = $(window).height() - 40;
$(".sourceView").css("height",$frameheight);

$(window).resize(function() {
    $frameheight = $(window).height() - 40 ;
    $(".sourceView").css("height",$frameheight);
});

});
</script>
</head>

  <body>

<!-- ========= Navigation ==== -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
</ul>
 </div>
```